# Spring Boot PasswordEncoder.matches always false

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot/ Angular project in my university. I'm struggeling with the matches function of BCryptPasswordEncoder, which always returns false.

## User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

## UserService.java

```
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public User register(UserDto userDto) throws EntityExistsException {
    User existingUser = userRepository.findUserByUserName(userDto.userName);
    if (existingUser != null)
        throw new EntityExistsException();

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUserName(userDto.userName);
    newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.password));
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    roles.add(Role.ROLE_USER);
    newUser.setRoles(roles);

    try {
        newUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    return newUser;
}

public boolean credentialsAreCorrect(String username, String password){
    User user = userRepository.findUserByUserName(username);
    if ( user == null)
        return false;

    return passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

In Angular I'm registering with following function:

```
  register() {
    const userName = 'testUser';
    const password = 'testPassword';

    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/user/register', {userName, password})
      .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
  }
```

After successfull registration I'm using the same credentials with the `UserService.credentialsAreCorrect()`method. But it always return false. The parameters of the `credentialsAreCorrect()` method are correct and the user is found.

## Edit

When I was debugging the server I noticed, that the value of the `password` parameter of the `credentialsAreCorrect(username, password)` method was always `"PROTECTED"`. I tought that was only visualy for debugging but the value really is `"PROTECTED"`.

I get the password from the request header in the following interceptor:

```
@Component
public class AuthChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    private static final String USERNAME_HEADER = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD_HEADER = "passcode";

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketAuthenticatorService webSocketAuthenticatorService;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
            final String username = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(USERNAME_HEADER);
            final String password = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(PASSWORD_HEADER);
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = webSocketAuthenticatorService.getAuthenticatedOrFail(username, password);

            accessor.setUser(user);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you check the password that is in your user table? Is it encoded? This should true passwordEncoder.encode(password).equals(user.getPassword())

Comment: @jordiburgos it is still `false`.

Comment: The password stored in the table is 5ec286bbc543b19796e995087ff885c5a3db5943e9d176cd6b559c52d28288980c76f9775e87902f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by changing the password header to `usercode`. I still don't understand, why the value gets `"PROTECTED"`, but at least it works.

## New Interceptor

```
@Component
public class AuthChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    private static final String USERNAME_HEADER = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD_HEADER = "usercode";

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketAuthenticatorService webSocketAuthenticatorService;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
            final String username = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(USERNAME_HEADER);
            final String password = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(PASSWORD_HEADER);
            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = webSocketAuthenticatorService.getAuthenticatedOrFail(username, password);

            accessor.setUser(user);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if the issue has been addressed but here are my five cents: instead of using  final String password = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(PASSWORD_HEADER); you have to use final String password = accessor.getPasscode(); as  StompHeaderAccessor.StompPasscode is not directly accessible, i.e toString() produces 'PROTECTED'. As you already mentioned accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("XXXX") works for the other fields. (from what I understood the client sets STOMP_PASSCODE_HEADER to "PROTECTED" and that's why this happens)